# How do I use a calculated value within a DATEFROMPARTS in SQL

Tags: t-sql, date

I need a calculated month value within DATEFROMPARTS function. The month has to be seven month prior to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP month.

This is what I tried:

DATEFROMPARTS(Year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-7, 1) as SevenMoAgo;

```
I will eventually use this in the following expression where '12-01-2018' is:

where RECORDED_SERVICE_STARTTIME > ='12-01-2018'

I later used

declare @CurMo AS INT;
declare @MonPri7 AS INT;
set @CurMo = Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
set @MonPri7 = (@CurMo -7);
Datefromparts(Year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), @MonPri7, 1) as SevenMoAgo;
```

This also did not work.

I get the following error message:

"Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid."

For the second code I get:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'Datefromparts'.

Comment: Debugging 099: "Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid." What are the argument values? Month number zero (or negative) might be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 7, 0)
```

Let me explain. First off, we need to understand that [SQL Server interprets 0 as 1900-01-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) as shown by the following DATEPART functions.

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, 0)  AS Year
     , DATEPART(MONTH, 0) AS Month
     , DATEPART(DAY, 0)   AS Day;
```

Which returns...

```
Year        Month       Day
----------- ----------- -----------
1900        1           1
```

Therefore, my SQL could be rewritten as...

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1900-01-01', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 7, '1900-01-01')
```

Now perhaps it is a little easier to see what is going on here. The DATEDIFF function returns the number number of months between 1900-01-01 and today (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) which is 1434.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1434 - 7, '1900-01-01')
```

Then we subtract 7 from 1434 which is 1427 and add that many months back to 1900-01-01.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1427, '1900-01-01')
```

Which yields 2018-12-01.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `@MonPri7 is equal to ZERO when you say (@CurMo -7)`

There are many different ways to calculate it, but if you want to fix your logic, you should use this:

```
declare @CurMo AS INT;
declare @MonPri7 AS INT;
set @CurMo = Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
set @MonPri7 = (@CurMo -7);
declare @Y int = Year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) -- <-- This is new variable
-- if 7 months ago is ZERO then you should go back to prev year December
if @MonPri7 = 0
begin
  set @MonPri7 = 12
  set @Y = @Y - 1
end
```

**Edit:**

```
declare @SevenMonthsAgo datetime;
select @SevenMonthsAgo = Datefromparts(@Y, @MonPri7, 1);

SELECT yourfields
FROM yourtable
where RECORDED_SERVICE_STARTTIME > = '01-01-2019' and
      RECORDED_SERVICE_STARTTIME > = @SevenMonthsAgo
```

Comment: I tried to incorporate this into my code, could not figure it out. Where would I put this and how?

Here is my code:

SELECT distinct [Facility_Code]
      ,[Facility_LOCATION_CODE]
      ,[Facility_COST_CENTER_CODE]
      ,[Client_ID]
      ,[CostCtrGrp_AdmitDate]
      ,[CostCtrGrp_DischargeDate]
      ,[RECORDED_SERVICE_STARTTIME]
FROM [FacReports].[dbo].[Fac_V_Report8009]

-- where RECORDED_SERVICE_STARTTIME > = '01-01-2019'
WHERE RECORDED_SERVICE_STARTTIME > = ?????